# Textmate: Defining a class/module called "Feature" breaks my themes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textmate, textmatebundles

In textmate, in Ruby, when I define a class or module whose name contains `Feature`, my themes break! By "break", I mean I loose coloration and indentation, it's like it was basic text.

```
#works fine
class Featurable
end

#break
class Model::Feature
end

#break
module Featured
end
```

If you could test that or tell me what's wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you also have the [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) bundle activated? I can see how that would interfere with Ruby highlighting.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably it. Sad... ^^